# Which of the following statements are valid for any ring $R$? a) For any $a, b, c, d \in R$, $(a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> TRUE/FALSE Which of the following statements are valid for any ring R?
>
> (a) For any $a, b, c, d \in R$, $(a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$.
>
> (b) For any $a, b\in R$, ${(a + b)}^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.
>
> (c) If $a, b\in R$ satisfy $ab = 0$, then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.
>
> (d) For any $a\in R$, $−(−a) = a$.

I believe that the first two are true because of the distributive property of rings. However, I am really not sure about the last two and can't think of any counter examples though I know their must exist some.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that (b) assumes commutativity, so it doesn't hold for noncommutative rings. Also, the rings with property (c) are called integral domains and not all rings are integral domains.

Comment: @RobWantsToLearn For (c), consider the ring of residue classes modulo $6$. Or the ring of $2\times2$ matrices over any ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is true (for the reason that you mentioned)

(b) is false. All you can say is that $(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2$. THis is different from $a^2+2ab+b^2$ if $a$ and $b$ don't commute.

(c) is false: take a ring with zero divisors;

(d) is true: since $a+(-a)=0$, by uniqueness of the opposite element you have $-(-a)=a$.